# Getting connection pool from webhook request with Actions On Google

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I’m trying to use the same connection pool to my database from the triggered webhook intent. I'm using the basic boilerplate (https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-webhook-boilerplate-java).

Every triggered intent does return `ActionRequest` to me, however, it doesn't contain `ServletContext`. So, how do I get normal request context using the `actions-on-google-java` library? (https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/google/actions/api/ActionRequest.kt)

---

I have tried to find alternative ways to get the pool, but my experience with Java is limited.

```java
// this is what i would like to achieve but ActionRequest is limited
@ForIntent("DB test")
public ActionResponse DbTest(ActionRequest request)
{
    ...
    DataSource pool = (DataSource) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("my-pool");
    try (Connection conn = pool.getConnection()) 
    { 
        // do database stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since you said your experience with Java is limited, have you tried using the Node.js client library instead?  https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `ActionRequest` providing the `ServletContext`, since it's independent of what handles the request.

Not too elegant, but you can create a method in your `MyActionsApp` (since you are using the basic boilerplate) to set the `ServletContext` from your request (`HttpServletRequest`) before you call `handleRequest`.

Create a constructor to pass that is also an option.